# c# check return datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need check **return datatable** and **count rows** in my asp net **GridView** code.

I tried this solution, I don't have error but the code not showing the alert and not count the rows.

My code below.

I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me in working this problem.

```
public DataTable GridViewBind()
{
    sql = " SELECT * FROM tbl; ";

    try
    {
        dadapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(sql, conn);
        dset = new DataSet();
        dset.Clear();
        dadapter.Fill(dset);
        DataTable dt = dset.Tables[0];
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        return dt;

        if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Alert", "alert('No data.');window.location='default.aspx';", true);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        dadapter.Dispose();
        dadapter = null;
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course the code isn't showing the alert.  You're returning from the method before that happens:

```
return dt;
// nothing after this will execute
if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Alert", "alert('No data.');window.location='default.aspx';", true);
}
```

The compiler should be warning you about this.  Don't ignore compiler warnings.

You can simply move your `return` statement to the end of the code block:

```
if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Alert", "alert('No data.');window.location='default.aspx';", true);
}
return dt;
```

Side-note: Your `catch` block is:

1. Throwing away meaningful stack trace information
2. Entirely superfluous

Just remove the `catch` block entirely and keep the `try` and `finally`.  If you ever do need to re-throw an exception from a `catch` block, just use the command:

```
throw;
```

This preserves the original exception, instead of replacing it with a new similar one.